# JavaScript get Info from table cells on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Every table row has a button "Show" located in a cell. On click of that button, I need to extract The text, contained in other cells of that exact row.

Example HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Info1</td>
    <td><input class="btn" value="Show" onclick="showRowInfo();" type="button"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Info2</td>
    <td><input class="btn" value="Show" onclick="showRowInfo();" type="button"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Info3</td>
    <td><input class="btn" value="Show" onclick="showRowInfo();" type="button"></td>
</tr>
```

What I want is: when I press (for example) the button on the 3rd row, to extract the text in the other 2 cells ("3" and "Info3").
I am looking for the implementation of the showRowInfo() in JavaScript, or at least a way to get the cells from the selected row.

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried?

Comment: `$(this).find('td').each(function() {
        MyFunction($(this));
    });` 
, but this will select the button clicked I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting an `onclick` attribute on each and every one of these buttons, I'd use a single event listener. Seeing as you added a jQuery tag, this code should do the trick:

```
$('table').on('click', '.btn', function()
{//replace table selector with an id selector, if you are targetting a specific table
    var row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        cells = row.find('td'),
        btnCell = $(this).parent();
    //set to work, you have the cells, the entire row, and the cell containing the button.
});
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9qsn9sf/4/)

If you want to do the same in vanillaJS:

```
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', function(e)
{//same applies here: querySelector('#tableID') would be preferable
    var target = (e = e || window.event).target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input' && target.className.match(/\bbtn\b/))
    {
        var btnCell = target.parentNode,
            row = (function(node)
            {
                while (node.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'tr')
                    node = node.parentNode;
                return node
            }(btnCell)),
            cells = row.cells;
        //set to work, you have the button-containing cell, the row and all of the cells
    }
}, false);
```

This technique is called event delegation, google it in case you're not familiar with the idea behind it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `this` in   showRowInfo(this)  ,

```
 onclick="showRowInfo(this);"

    function showRowInfo(elm) {
       alert($(elm).closest("tr").find("td:lt(2)").text());
  }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/p9qsn9sf/2/)